# Run docker in shell using PHP

Tags: php, shell, docker, terminal

Well, I need to run a `Docker` using a PHP function. I have a web page where pushing a link I execute a shell order using `shell_exec` or `exec`. This works for me if the execution is like an `ls` or something that expects a result. The problem is that if the command is to run the Docker (or for example a ping) it doesn't work.

What I want is when the user clicks the link, the shell will execute a command to run Docker in the browser, and the page will be redirected there.

For exemple, if I use `shell_exec('firefox');` this should open a new firefox browser, but it doesn't work. It seems that the browser is opened but few seconds later is closed.

This is the Docker execution that doesn't work.

```
public function executeDocker() {
      $result = shell_exec('docker run --rm -p 3838:3838 shiny/gsva_interactive /usr/bin/shiny-server.sh');

      echo "<br><br>Execution: ".$result;
    }
```

Comment: why not add a few things at the end, like `'docker run --rm -p 3838:3838 shiny/gsva_interactive /usr/bin/shiny-server.sh ; tail /var/log/xxx'?

Comment: The command works propertly, is the PHP function that does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved it. The problem was in the user group and permissions. In the system that I was using, `CentOS`, apache server uses a user called `apache`. This user needs to be in the `docker` group and reboot the services.

Now it works. Thanks to everyone who helped me.

Answer (score 1):

[shell_exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) will only return the output of a, in this case Docker, command only when the command has exited completely. In the case of ping (it will just keep pinging) and probably in the case of your Docker image, the process will never exit by itself, so it will never give a response.

Using [passthru](http://php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php) instead of shell_exec should give you the commandline output of your Docker script right back as a response.

If the Docker container is not meant to exit you should probably start it in [detached mode](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#detached--d) with `$containerId = shell_exec('docker run -d --rm -p 3838:3838 shiny/gsva_interactive /usr/bin/shiny-server.sh')`, so the docker run command will exit. This will return the container id, which you can use with [`$result = shell_exec("docker ps -f \"id=$containerId\"")`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/ps/) to check if the container is running correctly and redirect the user if it is.

Comment: I don't want the output, I just need to know that the Docker is executing correctly and find a way to control the execution.

Comment: Can you confirm that the Docker container exits? Because the point of my answer is that shell_exec will never give you *any* output if the Docker container never exits. Ping will also never exit with the default settings, so that is why `ls` works and `ping` does not.

Comment: I updated my question based on the assumption that you do not want the Docker container to exit.

Comment: I just tried your answer but it does not work. I don't know why the Docker is not executed and the container is not listed when I use `docker ps -a`.

Answer (score 1):

i was having the same issue running docker exec via shell_exec.
shell_exec('docker exec -it containerid /usr/bin/cmd);

Getting rid of the -i option worked for me.